# Rank within subsets of data in spotfire

Tags: subset, tibco, spotfire, dense-rank

I am trying to rank subsets of my data in spotfire.

Lets say I have a data table that has the following 6 columns:

`Individual, City, Zip Code, State, Amount1,and Amount2`.

There are thousands of Unique `Individuals` in each `Zip Code` and many `Zip Codes` within each `State`.  How would I display only the data from the top 5 `Zip Codes` within each `State` (as defined by the `SUM()`of `Amount1`)?

To summarize the order of operations; I want to sum up `Amount1` for each `Zip Code`, then Rank the `Zip Codes` in desc order within each `State` (just an intermediate step for explanatory purposes) and finally, only display the top 5 `Zip Codes` within each `State`.

All I could think of was to create a calculated column that would return the `Zip Code` if it satisfied my conditions and `NULL` if it did not.  I don't think its the best but here is the code I started with:

```
case  WHEN DenseRank(Sum(Sum([Amount1]) over [ZipCode]) over [State],"desc")<6 then [ZipCode] ELSE NULL END
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you let us know what errors you got with your current function, and provide a sample dataset?

Comment: It returned a single rank for each state, rather than ranking the Zip Codes within each state.  I then changed the DenseRank portion to DenseRank(Sum([Amount1]) over [ZipCode],"desc",[State]) and it fixed that issue (as in the zip codes were ranked within each state) but it still wasn't quite correct.  I created a column with only the ranking portion and it didn't correctly rank them.  An example would be the following:

Amount1 (Calc Rnk) [Act Rnk]
15000      (2)             [3]
20000      (1)             [1]
17500      (4)             [2]
5000        (5)             [5]
7500(3)[4]

Comment: Ok, currently you created a calculated column based on `DenseRank(Sum([Amount1]) over [ZipCode],"desc",[State])` and that gets you the ranking that you want--now all you need is to display the top 5 for each state, correct?

Comment: No, it did not rank them correctly.  My previous comment is hard to follow because it wouldn't let me start new rows but in my example, the ranking that was calculated based on the data set was the number in the parenthesis() and the correct ranking is the ranking in the brackets[].  As you can see, it ranked 15000 as the second largest amount when it should have been the third largest amount.  My actual dataset has about 200 columns and over 3 million rows, so I think there is something causing the sum() over or the ranking function to calculate incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification in the comments.

`DenseRank(Sum([A1]) OVER ([ZipCode]),"desc",[State]) as [Rank]`

The above function will give rank your `[ZipCode]` within its respective `[State]` based on the `SUM()` of an amount in column `[A1]`. `DenseRank()` will NOT skip a ranking number if there is a tie. The means you could have more than 5 `[ZipCode]` in your top 5. `Use Rank()` if you want to avoid this.

Then, you can create a calculated column for your filter panel, or just filter it in the "Limit Data using Custom Expressions" section of your chart.

`If([Rank] < 6,"Top 5", "Other")` as [Zip Rank in State]

Comment: The first expression worked.  Originally, I did not realize that calculated columns were calculated prior to any filters that are applied to the data, so once I included some logic in the expression to mimic the filters applied to the data, the zip codes were correctly ranked within each state.